# What Are the Advantages and Disadvantages of "Conductive Plastic" Potentiometers

Tags: audio, manufacturing

Maybe it's just the name putting me off, but I'm looking at potentiometers for a new design and I'm noticing that a lot of the cheap ones use "conductive plastic" as the resistive element. Is this an ultra-cheap construction method destined to fail? or is it just another option with some minor pros and cons?

The application is an audio volume adjustment, so longevity and smooth operation (both in terms of the feel, and electrical connection) are my priority specs. Drift and temp coefficient don't matter within reason.

Here's an example: [Bourns 3310P-101-103L](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/3310P-101-103L/2537832)

Comment: have you compared the stated load life and rotational life to other pots ? My guess is that they are easier to make from solutions that other films. but their noise index will be higher than for metal films. It might matter for hifi audio, if operated with substantial voltage across it

Comment: I always found CERMET pots reliable but now quadrature digital actuators are continuous and with a uC have high quality bearings and smooth action found in car radios and HiFi’s are replacing these.  If you need a pot , film pots are ok but burn up easily with low power but as in fixed film resistors are known for low electrical noise for low level signals.

Comment: "conductive plastic" used to be a big improvement (lower noise) over carbon track pots, which may be no longer made.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Was this cermet reliability for set and forget operations? Or where the pot was frequently adjusted?

Comment: It's just the name. Conductive plastic has traditionally been rather premium. I always have to pay more for them. Cermet is the more standard one that is superior in stability but worse in smoothness and wear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conductive plastic is generally the best choice for most audio doings.

It has lower noise then the carbon track parts and (usually) better rotational life then the cemrets, note that power dissipation is also lower.

Temperature coefficient is a weak point, but usually for audio you are in a ratiometric situation anyway.

The trick as ever is to NOT run DC thru the wiper, makes crackles as the things wear.

The things can be disturbingly expensive if you want good quality ones.

For volume service I would commend the active Bauxandall design as it can get you a reasonable law from a linear pot (Linear pots generally track much better then the log versions, which matters for stereo).

Comment: "*The trick as ever is to NOT run DC thru the wiper, makes crackles as the things wear.*" Can you elaborate? Plastic pots are used with DC quite frequently on joysticks.

Comment: @DKNguyen, yea but in that application you have DC across the track, but typically minimal DC current flowing in the wiper contact, it just connects to the ADC on the micro.

Comment: Oh, you're referring to where high audio currents is being directly throttled by the pot? I forget that audio volume is controlled that way. Seems so...boorish.

Comment: @DKNguyen, doesn't need to be that high, but it is what makes the old trick of using a 'law bending' resistor from one end of the pot to the wiper to turn a linear part into a loggish one rather iffy (The contact resistance between wiper and track can be rather variable).